# Making multiple DropdownList on same row/line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am struggling to make two `razor dropdownList (may be more) on line (row)`. I am not very much familiar to bootstrap. Appreciated if someone can guide me to solve my issue.

My razor code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Donor", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="row">
        Blood Group:    @Html.DropDownList("bloodGroupDD", ViewBag.lstBloodGroup as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Blood Group", new { @class = "form-control" })
        City:           @Html.DropDownList("cityDD", ViewBag.lstGroupCity as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select City", new { @class = "form-control" })
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
}
```

As you can see in the following image both dropdowns are on different lines (row). I don't want this. I want both on same row / line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
display: inline;
```

to the style of those two drop downs.

Answer (score 1):

You can add other divs inside the div with class="row" and make the use of bootstrap column classes such as col-md-4 on each if you want same width.

You can vary the width of each column with this.

Answer (score 1):

you can make it in many ways check this snippet

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown" style="display:inline">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   <div class="dropdown" style="display:inline">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I am using Razor DropDownList helper. I am not using <ul> <li> as you can see in my code. My drop downs are bind with viewbag data returned from server and not static using <ul> <li>

Comment: point is you need to give style="display:inline" to your dropdown, i know you are using viewbag data,but ultimately it renders in <ul> <li> inspect your web page,it's just a demonstration

Answer (score 0):

[image]As mentioned earlier you can use 'row' and 'col-md-4'. here is a working code with razor.

The same is found in - https://dotnetfiddle.net/WpsdIK (View the result in full screen)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Donor", FormMethod.Get))
{
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        Blood Group:    @Html.DropDownList("bloodGroupDD", ViewBag.lstBloodGroup as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Blood Group", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'> 
        City:           @Html.DropDownList("cityDD", ViewBag.lstGroupCity as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select City", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Donor", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="row" id="row_1">
        Blood Group:    @Html.DropDownList("bloodGroupDD", ViewBag.lstBloodGroup as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Blood Group", new { @class = "form-control" })
        City:           @Html.DropDownList("cityDD", ViewBag.lstGroupCity as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select City", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
}

$("#row_1").child().css("display","inline");
```